# Representing 2D char in XSD

Tags: xsd

I'm new to XSD. I have a structure which I need to represent in XSD:

```
struct  
{
  int num;
  char token[10]
  char value[20][10];
} test;
```

How do I mention "value" in XSD? I can represent other elements as:

```
<complexType name=test>
  <sequence>
    <element name='num' type='int'/>
    <element name='token' type='string' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='unbounded'/>
  </sequence>
</complexType>
```

This XSD will be used to generate C++ code

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following schema describes your data, producing XML that is fairly concise.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid Studio 2019 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="test">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="num" type="xs:int" />
                <xs:element name="token" type="ListOf10Chars" />
                <xs:element name="value" type="ListOf10Chars" minOccurs="20" maxOccurs="20" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:simpleType name="CharType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="1" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="ListChars">
        <xs:list itemType="CharType" />
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="ListOf10Chars">
        <xs:restriction base="ListChars">
            <xs:minLength value="10" />
            <xs:maxLength value="10" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid Studio 2019 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<test>
    <num>3281</num>
    <token>A b c d e f g h i j</token>
    <value>0 b c d e f g h i j</value>
    <value>1 b c d e f g h i j</value>
    <value>2 b c d e f g h i j</value>
    <value>3 b c d e f g h i j</value>
    <value>4 b c d e f g h i j</value>
    <value>5 b c d e f g h i j</value>
    <value>6 b c d e f g h i j</value>
    <value>7 b c d e f g h i j</value>
    <value>8 b c d e f g h i j</value>
    <value>9 b c d e f g h i j</value>
    <value>0 b c d e f g h i j</value>
    <value>1 b c d e f g h i j</value>
    <value>2 b c d e f g h i j</value>
    <value>3 b c d e f g h i j</value>
    <value>4 b c d e f g h i j</value>
    <value>5 b c d e f g h i j</value>
    <value>6 b c d e f g h i j</value>
    <value>7 b c d e f g h i j</value>
    <value>8 b c d e f g h i j</value>
    <value>9 b c d e f g h i j</value>
</test>
```